# Jquery dialog works only after the third click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

There is a problem in my jquery dialog, since it is opened only after the third click. Can anyone help? Here is the snippet. When auto open is set true it works. But it creates another problem using auto open true. I dont know whats wrong with my code. In each click this particular function is called.
thanks.

```
    function attachmentDialogBox(objId){
    var parentDiv = objId;
    if(parentDiv!=''){
        var source = $("#"+parentDiv+" input[name=sourceId]").val();
        var type = $("#"+parentDiv+" input[name=typeId]").val();
    }
    else{
        var source = $("input[name=sourceId]").val();
        var type = $("input[name=typeId]").val();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:"${createLink(controller: "fileAttachment",action: "rAttachmentDialog")}",
        data:{id:"${id}",module:"${module}",moduleType:"${moduleType}",source:"${source}",sourceId:source,attachmentUrl:"${attachmentUrl}",multiple:"${multiple?:1}",type:type},
        type:"post",
        success:function(data){
            $("#attachDocument").html(data);
            $("#attachDocument").dialog({
                title:"${module=="memberProfilePic"?"Upload Profile Image":"Attach Document"}",
                zIndex:1103,
                modal:true,
                autoOpen:false,
                width:"${module=="memberProfilePic"?355:"auto"}",
                resizable:false,
                draggable:false,
                close:function(){
                    $("#attachDocument").remove();
                    $("#dialogContainer").append("<div id='attachDocument'></div>");
                }
            });
            alert($("#attachDocument").val);
            $("#attachDocument").dialog('open');
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chaning it to this:

```
var dialog $("#attachDocument").dialog({...}); 
dialog.dialog("open");
```

I'm not entirely sure that $().dialog() returns the instance, but if it do, it should be a safer method

*Changed to solution found through suggestions in comment.*

Comment: There are no errors in any call.
and also error block didnt show any error as well.

Comment: @SauravDangol I was asking to `Martin` :)

Comment: @user3819192 what do you mean? Error is documented in the [api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @SauravDangol you didn't add any html, so I have to ask what you mean by "after the third click"? Do you mean after the ajax call have been made three times?

Comment: @user3819192 I don't think I can help any more without a jsfiddle example.

Comment: @MartinVerner Yes! When  the ajax was hit the 3rd time the dialog is opened.Also, the data is appended in the div successfully.Only the dialog is not opened.

Comment: @user3819192 I'm starting to think that the dialog is open but hiding behind something. I know it's a bit of a long shot, but since I can't see any running example that's the best I can do. Try adding this and see what is thinks. $( ".selector" ).dialog( "isOpen" )

Comment: @MartinVerner I alerted  $( ".selector" ).dialog( "isOpen" ). Its only true the third time. First two times nothing is alerted. Thanks

Comment: @SauravDangol i have another long shot. Try chaning it to this: var dialog $("#attachDocument").dialog({...}); dialog.dialog("open"); I'm not entirely sure that $().dialog() returns the instance, but if it do, it should be a safer method.

Comment: @MartinVerner It did work. But, it arose some latter problems. Guess I would have to figure that on my own. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SauravDangol perfect. :) I have changed my answer to reflect the solutions we found.